# Providing Rubygems with a Directory of Locally Developed Gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I develop various gems in parallel while I work. In my shell I have `RUBYOPT` set to include: `-r /path/to/my_load_path_script`. This script adds paths to all of my locally developed libraries to the load path; including it as the `-r` option means that the load path is patched every time I run Ruby. This way, I do not need to reinstall a gem every time I make a small change. This is the content of the script.

```
  ruby_lib = File.join ENV['PROJECT_ROOT_DIR'], 'ruby'
  local_gems = Dir.glob(File.join(ruby_lib, '*/'))
  local_gems.map! { |p| "#{p}/lib" }
  local_gems.map(&File.method(:absolute_path)).each &$LOAD_PATH.method(:unshift)
```

While convenient, this script has a small but noticeable effect on Ruby's startup time. I am wondering whether there is a way to eliminate this effect by somehow providing the directory where all my gems reside to RubyGems, so that it had can add my gems to the load path on demand in the same way it does with installed gems.

This would basically be equivalent to the `pip install --editable` functionality in Python, which allows you to install a package while putting the source wherever you want. I also know I can do something like this with bundler local overrides, but I'd like to avoid bundler here since I want my gems available in one-off scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the more gems you have installed, the slower your ruby will become. The effect is very negligible though.

"This way, I do not need to reinstall a gem every time I make a small change."

I myself do that though - I have 103 gems (they can be seen here https://rubygems.org/profiles/58718 though 95% of them are super small) and whenever I update them, I simply run my alias "r2", which is short for

cpruby;ruby setup.rb --quiet config;ruby setup.rb --quiet setup;ruby setup.rb --quiet install; rm setup.rb; rm InstalledFiles; rm .config;

where cpruby is an alias to copy setup.rb into the current working directory.

It is not pretty but effective and much faster than building a .gem and then installing that gem (although I also do that, on a fresh installation)

Ruby should already know your load path - the most important one is the one where a "require 'name'" will work, where name actually defaults to that very directory.

On my system this is:

/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A few questions/comments: (1) I don't know what setup.rb is-- I don't think your answer explains it sufficiently. Also please format the code. (2) The point of this question is to find a way to make my changes to locally developed gems available *without having to remember to run any command*; (3) "Ruby should already know your load path" does not make sense to me. The load path is an array of directories which has a default value, but does not include the dir with my locally developed gems.